# Indenting with white spaces, tabs, and how many spaces or the tab width

Tags: xcode, coding-style, text-editor

I know that this is more of a coding style, instead of a one right way of doing things. But, I'm a bit frustrated if I came across different indenting formats.

But, I would like to hear the reasons by various people on these issues:

- Do you use spaces or tabs? Tabs with spaces? Any difference with "Tab insert space", instead of using the space key directly?
- How many spaces to indent each line of code? Why?
- Does different code has different style that is more suitable for each of them?

Is there a way to "visually" indent code without actually writing the indent? So it won't ruin the original indenting? It seems unlikely.

I'm using Xcode, so it's better if you have advice for Xcode projects.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, this should at least be community wiki.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should always use the coding style that the project is already using if you are modifying an existing project.

That being said, if you are able to choose your own coding style for a new project I suggest that you use tabs to indent code and not spaces -- here is why. By using spaces you force all of the other developers working on the project to conform to your indentation preference whether that be 2 spaces or 4 or 8 (or whatever). But by using tabs each developer can view the code using their own preference. You should uses spaces and not tabs to format text (to line up variable names one per line, or to line up multi-line comments) because that will work with any tab width preference. However, when you indent code use tabs not spaces. In short, indent with tabs because indenting with spaces is rude.

Comment: Correction, Xcode uses tabs inserts spaces by default. It seems they're going against your advice.

Comment: +1 on the use of tabs instead of spaces (I personally set my tab size to just 2 spaces). Also, why use 2, 4 or 8 characters when 1 will do? Only problem I've found with tabs is when posting code samples into forums etc. spaces often format better in this instance.

Comment: Jesse Armand: Xcode is wrong :) 

Goto Xcode->Preferences->Indentation Check the 'Tab key inserts tab instead of spaces' checkbox. Click the Ok button. 

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeWorkspace/100-The_Text_Editor/text_editor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002679-SW64

Comment: Why would you suggest to format the code such that it looks different on every person's computer? Use spaces.

Comment: For the same reason a person shouldn't use font pixel sizing in CSS, rather use em sizing. Using space indents to me feels similar to trying to force formatting into 80-chars-per-line.  Long text strings that a coder chooses to break up over several lines and concatenate for readability, may be easier to read. And if left to wrap naturally or stretch, may look awkward. But the latter feels more appropriate because the display decision is up to the particular viewer's settings, ie wordwrap or no-wordwrap. Of course, standardized formatting indentation isn't universal across all editors.

Comment: +1 I have a religious devotion to tabs over spaces.

Comment: *"Why would you suggest to format the code such that it looks different on every person's computer?"* Because you shouldn't care what your code looks like on my screen. That's up to *me*, not you. And the only way it can be up to *me* is if you use tabs.

Comment: Xcode uses by default spaces, thus most iOS/OS X's project code style is spaces. So end of the story for Xcode projects (btw I also prefer spaces).

Comment: I used to read articles said that one should always uses spaces to indent rather than tabs, because spaces is static: It will be the same on any editor with any settings. But now I finally figured out that the tabs way is much more flexible and less bothering.

Comment: Using tabs over spaces actually messes up my code indentation (appears far too wide) when I push to GitHub.

Answer (score 29):

- spaces because they render the same everywhere
- indent-width is context-dependent.  runaway indentation is bad.  generally, languages where you cannot easily reset the indentation to sane levels through named abstraction items (functions or methods) need narrow indentation.
- yes, see previous bullet

the claim that tabs allow individual developers to use different tab widths is false.  consider

```
typedef __LA_SSIZE_T archive_write_callback(struct archive *,
                                            void *_client_data,
                                            const void *_buffer,
                                            size_t _length);
```

if this was produced with tabwidth of 2, it would look like this with tabwidth = 4:

```
typedef __LA_SSIZE_T archive_write_callback(struct archive *,
                                                                                        void *_client_data,
                                                                                        const void *_buffer,
                                                                                        size_t _length);
```

conversely, if it was produced with tabwidth = 8 and displayed with tabwidth = 4, the result would be

```
typedef __LA_SSIZE_T archive_write_callback(struct archive *,
                        void *_client_data,
                        const void *_buffer,
                        size_t _length);
```

so if a project style guide requires tabs and says function parameters need to align as in the first code display, then there's a single correct tab width.

([another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4443877/209605) presents the same argument.)

**a long-overdue edit:**

i wholeheartedly agree with the opening sentence of the accepted answer, which is

> You should always use the coding style that the project is already using if you are modifying an existing project.

the rest of that answer is, excuse me, rubbish, and i tried to explain why above.

the question of indentation style should only come up at the very beginning of any project, once it's settled it's done.  i *do* believe that spaces are better than tabs, and have (again, i believe) rational arguments in support of my position, etc.  but i'm not going to start discussions on this topic because they're useless: most programmers i met support their preferences with irrational arguments, and the rest have settled for a style which works best with their tooling (like me: *"spaces because they render the same everywhere"*), which i have no influence over in general.

anecdote: i once worked on a project which underwent a change of newlines, from `\r\n` to `\n`, and it turned out to be a pain in the ass any time we needed to go past the revision in `svn blame`.  `s/newlines/indentation/`, and you have a nice argument against massive indentation changes in a running project.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still inclined to using spaces.

Comment: I strongly agree: the coding style of the project is what must be conformed to.  I'm trying to come to a rational middle-ground at the moment and scouring SO and IRC for opinions on both sides. Both have good points; I'm use tabs since their implementation at coding-time seems more universally standard, whether or not they break in different viewers. Unfortunately, I must use 5 different editors regularly for various platforms and code-time space indentation behaviour is NOT standard, or comfortable, despite being more universally readable at contribution-time.

Answer (score 3):

An advantage to spaces vs tabs is alignment when wrapping long lines.  If you use tabs, no matter what you do, the lines below will most likely not align, unless the editor has the same settings.

For example:

```
    result = variable_one + variable_two + variable_three +
             variable_four;
```

If you use tabs, how to ensure that 'variable_four' will show up aligned if tab indentation changes?

Comment: Okay, good to know that it's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are different programming languages with very different syntax. The syntax is crucial in choosing a coding style. Especially the tab size (number of spaces) that you will chose will depend on how many levels you need to have. In HTML for instance there are many levels, and there it makes no sense to have a big tab size, it even makes no sense in using tabs.. you just use spaces. Another very important aspect is the IDE you use. In some IDE's you are encouraged to use tabs (in Visual Studio you have the nice facility to add/remove tabs to more than one line (TAB to add, SHIFT+TAB to remove) and so on. 
Projects have different indent sizes because people use different indent settings (even in the same code) or because they use different editors or because the project includes code from other projects or even simply because people have different preferences or even different sized monitors.
I work in Visual Studio C++ and VB.NET, indent is tab based(3 lines) and tabs do not insert spaces.

Comment: Xcode is using spaces by default. I'm not sure what is the reason.

Comment: In HTML I use a tab size that aligns the lower diagonal segment of the '<' on a tag and the tag below which is one level deeper, because it looks good. Usually it's two spaces.

Answer (score 2):

- I simply use the defaults of the editor I'm currently working in, but if I have the choice I use tabs because it means less invisible characters to manage. I have one editor that wholly manages indentation for me (REALbasic), another editor that manages indentation for me, allows for spaces as prefix but formatting gets wonky if I leave them in (Applescript), and there's Xcode.
- I see 4 spaces more than another number for space-based indentation, so I go with that if I have to.
- I've found that every community more or less has a standard that has been placed in example code, so I just go with that otherwise tabs then 4 spaces. Simple.

Honestly, I gave up on the indentation fight a long time ago and expend my brain power on other, what I feel are more important, code-related issues like good variable and functions names. Any reasonable code editor can help you manage poorly-placed or complex indentation but none of them can help with sorting out poorly-written or complex code.

Comment: I understand. I also follow the project original indentation settings. But, it frustrates me when I'm working on multiple projects with different indentation settings.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your IDE and your "tab inserts spaces" option, it's a nice shortcut over using the spacebar.  I.e. at 3 indentation levels with 3 spaces per tab, you press the Tab key 3 times instead of the spacebar 9 times.  The net effect is the same - you inserted 9 spaces - but with 1/3 the number of keystrokes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I normally indent HTML at 2 spaces and procedural code at 4.  This is one area where tabs vs. spaces makes a difference - if someone else on the team preferred 3 and 3, the code would be formatted for them according to their preferred style while remaining formatted on my screen according to my own preference.  However, I use spaces, not tabs...  :)

Comment: I'm still wondering whether tabs insert spaces will have different result compared to using spacebar directly. If it's the same, what's the point of using tabs with no spaces insertion?

Comment: @Jesse - Tab stops are at fixed positions across the screen, based on your tab settings.  So when using tabs instead of spaces, indentation will be consistent regardless of your particular settings.  If a particular line of code is indented at 3 tab stops, it will always be at 3 tab stops whether a tab is 2 spaces or 10.

Comment: Yes, I just experimented with that. The issue with using tabs is (as John said) if someone else is not using tabs.

Answer (score 0):

A benefit of using spaces instead of tabs can make printing your code a bit nicer, especially if you're using a non-typewriter style font. I usually use a width of 3 spaces for each 'level' of indentation.

Comment: Yes, a good print result is nice, but I think we can limit the standard of indentation for data on the disk or source code repository.

Comment: @Jesse - "if you're using a non-typewriter style font" (ie. proportional as opposed to fixed width) then I would have thought it was the other way round!? You would need to use _tabs instead of spaces_ in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Because I prefer proportional fonts at a specific 15pt size, I set a TAB to be 37 pixels.

I don't mind that you use FOUR SPACES as long as you also use a font where a SPACE is 37/4 pixels wide.  Or TWO SPACES as long as you also use a font where a SPACE is 37/2 pixels.  Or even THREE SPACES, as long as you also use a font where a SPACE is 37/3 pixels.

Otherwise, a TAB works great for both us.