# Inserting a tab when XCode is set to "Indents in leading whitespace"

Tags: xcode, xcode6

As part of my XCode project, I have a tab-delimited text file that I'd like to be able to edit from within XCode.

The tab key is set to "Indents in leading whitespace" under `Preferences`->`Text Editing`->`Indentation`, and I'd rather leave it as is given that the project is well underway (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335966/indenting-with-white-spaces-tabs-and-how-many-spaces-or-the-tab-width)).

Is there a way to insert a tab somehow (besides copying and pasting) despite this setting? (Not "\t" but an actual chunk of whitespace.) Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was a very simple solution sitting right in the File Inspector (⌘-⌥-1 to show):

Just toggle the `Indent Using` option (under "Text Settings") to `Tabs`